# C# Events and Inheritance

Tags: c#, events, inheritance

I am very raw and new to C# and GUI events in general.

I have a base class:

```
public partial class BaseClass : UserControl
{
  private event DataChangeEventHandler mDataChangeEvent;
  public event DataChangeEventHandler DataChange
  {
    add
    {
      mDataChangeEvent += value;
    }
    remove
    {
      mDataChangeEvent -= value;
    }
   }
  }

  public delegate void DataChangeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

  ...
  ...

  protected virtual void Control1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //some code do something
    if(mDataChangeEvent != null)
    {
      EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
      mDataChangeEvent(this, e);
     }
  }
}
// derived class
public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
...
...
  protected override void Control1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    base.Control1_SelectedValueChanged(sender, e);
  }
}
```

I ran my code through the debugger. Whenever I change my dropdown control to another value, it  will hit break point on my derive class' Control1_SelectedValueChanged then call the base class' Control1_SelectedValueChanged. However, mDataChangeEvent is null. Why?

Comment: Which means that nobody is listening to that event. You missed subscribing the event?

Comment: Hi Sriram, first off thank you. That makes sense. Does my derived class subscribes to that event or the class, CallingClass, that uses my derived class who, by-the-way, was instantiated by AnotherClass or does my AnotherClass subscribe to that event? I hope make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form that uses this control has to have a handler for the event. Something like:

```
BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass();
baseClass.DataChange += <EventHandlerHere>
```